# KineticJS - new Shape from String or Array

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have several shape definitions stored in files, i.e.

```
Kinetic.Rect({width : 150,height : 50,stroke : 'black',fill :'#00D2FF',strokeWidth : .5,cornerRadius : 25,name : 'rect'});
```

This line (among with others) are available through an array. Normally I create this shape as follows:

```
rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
            width: 150,
            height: 50,
            stroke: 'black',
            fill: fill,
            strokeWidth: .5,
            cornerRadius: 25,
            name: 'rect'        
        });
```

How I create this shape from an array/string?

(rect = new   "string from array[xx]")?

Comment: If I add the word new to the string/array and do it like this: rect = eval(array[xx]), it works only without the "fill : '#00D2FF'" option. With this option I get "Unexpected token ILLEGAL".

Comment: I'd probably avoid having the entire definition (including the Kinetic.Rect) and only store your properties as JSON array of object properties. Then I'd loop through this array and create a new Kinetic.Rect(shapeProperties[i])

Comment: If you're creating different shape types, I'd probably include a new property in your objects that includes a type='rect' or circle or whatever and then include some logic to create a different Kinetic shape based on that type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KineticJS shapes (like Rect) are defined using a plain javascript object containing your desired properties.

Note: you're fill definition relies on a variable `fill`.  Be sure `fill` is valid!

```
// define a rectangle

var rectDefinition1={
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: .5,
    cornerRadius: 25        
};
```

You can feed this definition into a function like this that creates a Kinetic.Rect from your definition and applies a specific new name to that object.

```
// function to create a Kinetic.Rect from the rectangle definition

function makeRectFromObject(myObject,newName,newFill){

    var rect=new Kinetic.Rect(myObject);

    rect.name(newName);

    rect.fill(newFill);

    return(rect);

}
```

You would use the creation function like this:

```
// Use like this

var rect1=makeRectFromObject(rectDefinition1,"rect1","red");

// add the newly created rect to the layer and redisplay the layer

layer.add(rect1);
layer.draw();
```

If you want to store and retrieve your object definitions, you can use JSON:

```
// serialize your javascript object to a JSON text string 
// This is a regular text string that can be stored in a file or database.

var myRectDefinitionAsJSONText = JSON.stringify(rectDefinition1);

// create a javascript object from your JSON text string

var rectDefinition1= JSON.parse( myRectDefinitionAsJSONText );
```